# Why is my VirtualBox/LinuxMint ISO not prompting me for an install?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, linux-mint, iso-image

I downloaded the latest version of VBox. Then I downloaded an ISO of Linux Mint 16. I then created a VBox Linux (Other) VM and pointed it at my downloaded ISO. Then I started the VM, expecting to go through an installation process for Linux Mint.

No such installation happened, and Mint fired right up. It even gave me a default user ("mint").

My question: why was I not prompted for an installation process here? I wanted to do things like set up swap partitioning, and add a preliminary user to the machine, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mint ISO boots into a live-DVD version of Mint running directly from the mounted ISO. This is why you see the user as "mint". Think of it as a "trial run". :)

You will find a Setup/Install icon on the booted up desktop, which will start the actual install process. This installs the OS on your (virtual) disk and allows you to configure partitions, users, etc.